# barplot discrete variables for 2 groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe with a column of 'Y' or 'N' for 2 groups eg:

```
drug<-c("Y","Y","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N")
   group<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)                 
df<-data.frame(drug,group)
```

I want to make barplots of the 'Y'/'N' for both groups with the two groups beside each other.
I've tried various things with ggbarplot and get weird plots out

```
ggbarplot(my_matches, x = "group", y = "drug", 
                 color = "group", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#FC4E07"))
```

and have tried making tables and plotting these as barplots like

```
counts0<-df[which(df$group==0),]
counts1<-df[which(df$group==1),] 

grp0<-table(counts0$drug)
grp1<-table(counts1$drug)
s<- as.data.frame(t(rbind(grp0,grp1)))

barplot(s$grp0, s$grp1,beside=T)
```

As you can tell, I'm a beginner and have been driving myself mad trying to solve this. Please help!

Comment: What's `my_matches` ? It's not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

First, there's no need to create vectors as data frame columns, and `df` is not a great variable name (there's a function of the same name). Create your data frame in one step like this:

```
mydata <- data.frame(drug  = c("Y","Y","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N"),
                     group = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Second: if you're working with data frames, it's worth learning [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html). So install it, along with `ggplot2`, then load:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Now we can count Y/N by group:

```
mydata %>% 
  count(group, drug)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  group drug      n
  <dbl> <fct> <int>
1     0 N         3
2     0 Y         5
3     1 N         5
4     1 Y         3
```

And plot counts versus group. We need to convert the groups to factors, since group is a categorical variable:

```
mydata %>% 
  count(group, drug) %>% 
  mutate(group = factor(group)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group, n)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = drug))
```

[image]